# How do we know that the point of discontinuities of $f$ can be covered by at most countable many rectangles?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 96, in the proof of the theorem stating that *a bounded function over a rectangle $Q$ is integrable iff the set of discontinuities of $f$ over $Q$ has measure zero*, it is argued that

[image]

[image]

However, how do we know that there exists at most countably many such rectangle $R$ so that their union has also measure zero ?

Similarly how do we know that there is only a finite number of $R$s that contains the points of $D_m ''$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"However, how do we know that there exists at most countably many such rectangle $R$ so that their union has also measure zero ?"

Each Bd $R$ has measure $0.$ There are only finitely many $R.$ Thus the union of all of these has measure $0.$ No claim is being made about a union of rectangles having measure $0.$ (I am confused about what you are calling $R,$ which should throughout the proof denote a subrectangle coming from the partition $P.$)

"Similarly how do we know that there is only a finite number of $R$s that contains the points of $D_m ''$ ?"

Because there are only finitely many $R$s to begin with; they are determined by the partition $P.$

Comment: How do we know that the partition $P$ contains finitely many rectangles then ?

Comment: I assumefd that a partition of a rectangle induced only finitely many subrectangles. Is that not true?

Comment: I don't see any reason for that to be true. I mean as far as I know, the author did not make any such assumption.

Comment: What is the definition in Munkres? It's absolutely standard for a partition of a rectangle to give finitely many subrectangles.

Comment: In a Lindelof space every open covering of a closed set has a countable subcovering.